# Keyboard very unresponsive after resume (just upgraded to Lucid)

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, suspend, ubuntu-10.04

Yesterday I upgraded first from Jaunty to Karmic, and immediately after that to Lucid. Most things seems to have gone well, but I have a problem with suspend/resume. After resuming my Compaq-branded wireless keyboard becomes very unresponsive. If I type quickly, only about every third key press comes through. It's possible to type if I press every key for half a second or so. It doesn't help to switch to a virtual console (with Alt-F1 for example), the problem is the same there. The wired mouse works fine. After a reboot, everything is normal.

Is this a known problem? (Googling didn't help, there are similar problems, but I didn't find this one.)

In what logs should I look to diagnose the problem?

**EDIT:**

Today, after resuming the computer, I tried to unplug the wireless receiver and plug it in again (into another USB port), and that made the problem go away. Not permanently, I presume, but it will work as a workaround until I can solve this.

Comment: I can remember reading about such a problem (but I've no idea where, sorry)...the problem seemed to be that the keyboard forgets it's setting from the OS, and doesn't get set again or something like that. Does something change if you open the Keyboard settings and save them ones more?

Comment: @Bobby: No, unfortunately not.